# QLabel pixmap works in Designer but not in the actual program

Tags: android, qt, qt-creator

I've set a company logo above the main menu. This is what it looks like in QtDesigner:

[image: image description]
I distorted the logo on purpose. The point is that the image **is** there.

This is the resource folder in QtCreator project view:
[image: image description]

This is what it looks like on my android phone:
[image: image description]

So, well, what's going on here? I see no file errors in console (and loading CSS files from resources works form me). One thing that is possibly relevant is that the image is a SVG file.

Answer (score 0):

SVG was indeed an issue. While QtDesigner displays SVG without problems, the actual Qt library cannot handle that. I used this code to test it:

```
QPixmap pixmap;
if (!pixmap.load( ":/logo.svg" )) {
    QDebug("Failed to load main svg logo.");
    if (!pixmap.load( ":/logo.png" )) {
        QDebug("Failed to load main png logo.");
    }
    else {
        QDebug("PNG logo loaded.");
    }
}
else {
    QDebug("SVG logo loaded.");
}
```